# Interact between Jenkins Build parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Using the [Filesystem List Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Filesystem+List+Parameter+Plug-in), I am able to allow a job user to select a filename, I want to than be able to load this file (e.g. act onChange of the plugin) and update a MultiLine String Parameter (basically load the file and allow a user to edit it).

Is that at all possible? some plugins out of the box ? or is that just heading towards abuse of the simple jenkins UI ?

Comment: Show us some code please. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure what is missing. There is no code involved. This is simple setup of jenkins parameter plugins. I want to have interaction between parameters. When one parameter field is selected, another parameter field will be updated.

Comment: No worries. Are you using declarative pipeline or scripted?

Comment: Using declarative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a shot in the dark, but would that work for you?

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        //your file param handling
    } 
    stages {    
        stage("Interactive_Input") {
            steps {
                script {
                def userInput = input(
                 id: 'userInput', message: 'Testing', 
                 parameters: [
                 [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: $fileContents, description: 'modify please', name: 'contents']
                ])
                echo ("The modified contents: "+userInput['contents'])

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's [an old open bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34521) that might be of an issue here.